# Calendário Android com eventos

Tags: java, android, calendar

No momento só tenho este calendário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou a utilizar o **MaterialCalendarView**

```
    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_centerInParent = "true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
            app:mcv_selectionColor="#00FFFF" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pretendo agendar eventos numa determinada data, afim de que essas **atividades fiquem visíveis no calendário**.

*exemplo*: Se no dia 5 de Agosto tenho um aniversário agendado, gostaria que nesse dia algo o **descrevesse**. Ou por imagens ou por textos. Tal como ilustro na figura seguinte.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Algumas ideias para o que pretendo?

Answer (score 1):

Nokas,

Para definir eventos você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
calendarView.addEvent(new Event(date, "Feriado X"));
```

Para destacar os eventos, você precisará utilizar **decorators** em datas específicas, onde você define como deverá ser essa personalização de acordo com o tipo de data.

Na documentação há um exemplo de como colocar um ponto nas datas específicas:

```
public class EventDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    private final int color;
    private final HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

    public EventDecorator(int color, Collection<CalendarDay> dates) {
        this.color = color;
        this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return dates.contains(day);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.addSpan(new DotSpan(5, color));
    }
}
```

Chamando o **decorator**:

```
calendarView.addDecorators(new EventDecorator(this));
```

Poderá definir também mais de um decorator para casos diferentes:

```
public class FeriadoDecorator implements DayViewDecorator{
    @Override
    public void decorate(DayView view,Context context) {
        view.setBackground(generateCircleDrawable(color));
    }
}
```

Adicionando decorator personalizado:

```
widget.addDayViewDecorator(new FeriadoDecorator (), dates);
```

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md

---

Você poderá utilizar estilos personalizados para o primeiro dia do mês, por exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_bg_color" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_bg_color" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/red_circle" />
```

red_circle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:innerRadius="0dp"
   android:shape="ring"
   android:thicknessRatio="2"
   android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/selected_color" />
```

selected_bg_color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/selected_color"/>
<size android:width="120dp" android:height="120dp"/>
```

**Fonte:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/37881374/5626568

Comment: Muito obrigada! Irei testar

Comment: Já testei! Consegui colocar um "ponto" colorido numa determinada data, mas ao invés de colocar esse ponto testei colocar uma pequena string e não funcionou...

Comment: Collection<CalendarDay> colldates;
        colldates = new HashSet<>();
        CalendarDay eventDay2 = CalendarDay.from(2017, 07, 18);
        colldates.add(eventDay2);
        materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new EventDecorator(colldates, "Nokas")); **Alterei a Classe EventDecorator o método decorate ** view.addSpan(new String(n));  O que estou a fazer de errad0? @ℛɑƒæĿ

Comment: @Nokas editei a resposta, coloquei um exemplo no final...

Comment: Obrigada mas testei e ainda não dá @ℛɑƒæĿ não está a aceitar o new TextSpan, não reconhece.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [`DayViewDecorators`](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md). Seria algo como:

```
calendarView.addDecorators(new EventDecorator(
    getResources().getColor(R.color.coarCalendar), calendarDays))
```

Veja um exemplo simples que [está na documentação](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md):

```
public class EventDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    private final int color;
    private final HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

    public EventDecorator(int color, Collection<CalendarDay> dates) {
        this.color = color;
        this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return dates.contains(day);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.addSpan(new DotSpan(5, color));
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada! Irei testar!

Comment: Já testei! Consegui colocar um "ponto" colorido numa determinada data, mas ao invés de colocar esse ponto testei colocar uma pequena string e não funcionou...

Comment: Collection<CalendarDay> colldates; colldates = new HashSet<>(); CalendarDay eventDay2 = CalendarDay.from(2017, 07, 18); colldates.add(eventDay2); materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new EventDecorator(colldates, "Nokas")); **Alterei a Classe EventDecorator o método decorate ** view.addSpan(new String(n)); O que estou a fazer de errad0? @acklay

Comment: @Nokas estava alterando aqui pra colocar a string.

Comment: foi exatamente isso que fiz, como pode ver no exemplo que coloquei no comentário, mas não está a funcionar infelizmente :-( @acklay

Comment: @Nokas está aparecendo algum erro?

Comment: não, não está a aparecer @acklay será que a string não aparece devido às dimensoes do meu MaterialCalendarView?

Comment: @Nokas tenta colocar apenas um letra para exemplo. Estou faendo um teste aqui.

Comment: testei apenas com uma letra e não deu @acklay

Comment: @Nokas você usou o addEvent como o Rafael exemplificou?

Comment: utilizei apenas o addDecorator... @acklay

Comment: @Nokas tenta fazer usando addEvent  em vez de DayViewDecorator

Comment: estou com um problema, o MaterialCalendarView não me permite fazer o addEvent @acklay